# CSS selector for element within element with inline style?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, inline-styles

Is there a CSS selector to target elements with inline styles? So can I target the first span but not the 2nd with CSS only?

If not, can this be done with jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/TYCNE/

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span>target</span>
</p>

<p>
    <span>not target</span>
</p>
​
```

Comment: It depends. Are you only interested in the presence of the inline style attribute, or do you need to select by a specific inline style? Selecting by just merely having the attribute is easy and reliable, but having a specific inline style... not so much, unless you can control the markup.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
p[style="text-align: center;"] {
  color: red;
}
```

However this is ugly.

Comment: And fails, unless the `style` string is an *exact* match.

Comment: Plus one for David's comment. If the paragraph has any other styling associated with it then you have to include that in the CSS declaration.

Comment: I've had a case where IE ignored such a rule.

Comment: Check developer's tool in IE, sometimes IE convert styles such as hex color values into RGB values. You need to match those changes as well.

Answer (score 60):

A bit late to the tea party but thought I would share the solution I found & use.

@simone's answer is perfect if you can match the style attribute exactly. However, if you need to target an inline style attribute that may have other inline styles associated with it you can use:

```
p[style*="text-align:center;"]
```

> "*=" means "match the following value anywhere in the attribute
>   value."

For further reference or more detailed information on other selectors see this blog post on css-tricks.com:

**The Skinny On CSS Selectors**

http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/#rel-anywhere

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to apply styles to a particular rule declaration you can also use style*. This will match all elements that have the inline style, regardless of the value applied.

```
div[style*="background-image"] {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
​p[style] span {
  color: red;   
}​
```