# Can I access an element with inline styling like an input?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know I can style elements like inputs using `input[type=text] {}`, but can I do the same with elements with inline styling?

Something like this:

```
<div style="float: right;"></div>

div[style=float:right;] {}
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139690/css-selector-for-element-within-element-with-inline-style

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors .... search a little before post

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it didn't work until I realized that it wasn't an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use CSS attribute selectors; For instance [sub-string `*=` selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):

```
div[style*="float: right"],
div[style*="float:right"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write as following

```
div[style="float:right;"] {
/* propery */
}
```